# Cannot change default colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, colormap

I am trying to set the **default** **colormap** (not just the color of a specific plot) for matplotlib in my jupyter notebook (Python 3). I found the commands: plt.set_cmap("gray") and mpl.rc('image', cmap='gray'), that should set the default colormap to gray, but both commands are just ignored during execution and I still get the old colormap.

I tried these two codes:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('image', cmap='gray')
plt.hist([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.set_cmap("gray")
plt.hist([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

They should both generate a plot with gray tones. However, the histogram has colors, which correspond to the first two colors of the default colormap. What am I not getting?
[image: myresultofbothcodes]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use matplotlib's set\_cmap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299577/how-to-use-matplotlibs-set-cmap)

Comment: Thanks! But in your link it's not the default behaviour. But it did tell me that what I need to change is not the colormap but the color cycle. When you get this, then the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397944/how-to-set-the-default-color-cycle-for-all-subplots-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Chris, I found the issue, it's not the default **colormap** that I need to change but the default **color cycle**. it's described here: [How to set the default color cycle for all subplots with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397944/how-to-set-the-default-color-cycle-for-all-subplots-with-matplotlib)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

# Set the default color cycle
colors=plt.cm.gray(np.linspace(0,1,3))
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=colors)
plt.hist([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the color argument in matplotlib plot function.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], color=['gray','gray'])
```

with this method you have to specify the color scheme for each dataset hence an array of colors as I have put it above.

Comment: I need to change the color map in the whole notebook. Not just for one plot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of matplotlib between prio and **2.0** you need to use `rcParams` (still working in newer versions):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'
```

Comment: Same problem. Default colormap unchanged. Does the code work for you? I'm using python 3.0 and jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two data sets your are passing, you'll need to specify two colors.

```
plt.hist([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], color=['black','purple'])
```

Comment: I need to change the color map in the whole notebook. Not just for one plot.